# terraform import existing azure resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I want to create subnet in my existing vnet which is present in azure. I found a command to import resource terraform import .  but how do i use the resource details example: vnet resource group in the code.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                           = var.vnet_name
  address_space                  = var.vnet_address_space
  resource_group_name            = var.subscriptionrg_name
  location  }
```

I ran the command and found that the dns server which we earlier present are now deleted. Does that means i have to define everything in my code and import. Or is there any other way to use existing resources.

Comment: terraform import <terraform resource name>.<resource label> <resource id>

Answer (score 3):

First just define an empty block like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
}
```

Then, run `terraform import` command to import existing resource into your Terraform state. Afterward, execute the `terraform show` to print out the TF state into the screen. Finally, you can copy the content of printed `"azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet"` block into the actual block in .tf file.

Comment: I came caross terraform data source. How does terraform import differs from data source. Because i just want to create a subnet in an existing vnet and which is the best way to go for either by import or data ?

Comment: Hi @Mitanshi, while the use of `data sources` allows a Terraform configuration to make use of information defined outside of Terraform, `terraform import` command imports existing resources into the state.

Comment: So in that case data source is used in scenario where we have to just use existing resource information, as in my case i want to use existing vnet which was defined outside terraform and cretae subnet using terraform. Thanks @adp that really clarifies.